# Avoid having my character fall off the screen in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, border, helper

I am in early stages of making a Jetpack Joyride style game in pygame.
I currently have when you press space it moves the character up and when you aren't holding space the character falls to the ground, but the problem is there is no ground it, there are no borders around my screen so the character can just disappear.
The code I have so far for the game is below and I have tried to add those borders / blocks whatever its called but I just can't find a way that works. If anyone could help that would be great thanks

```python
import pygame
pygame.init()

width=800
height=800
x=(width*0.45)
y=(height*0.6)
bgspeed=30
x_change=0
y_change=0
speed=2.5

mainDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption("jetpack")

bg=pygame.image.load("bg.png")
bg=pygame.transform.scale(bg,(width,height))
bgX=0
bgX2=bg.get_width()

dababy_jetpack=pygame.image.load("dababy.png")
dababy_jetpack.convert()
rect=dababy_jetpack.get_rect()
rect.center=0,0
player_rect=dababy_jetpack.get_rect(topleft=(200,200))
mainDisplay_rect=mainDisplay.get_rect()

jetpacker=pygame.image.load("dababy.png")
jetpacker=pygame.transform.scale(jetpacker,(100,200))

mainDisplay_rect=mainDisplay.get_rect()
player_rect=jetpacker.get_rect()



def redrawWindow():
    mainDisplay.blit(bg,(bgX,0))
    mainDisplay.blit(bg,(bgX2,0))
    pygame.display.update()

clock=pygame.time.Clock()

def test(x,y):
    mainDisplay.blit(jetpacker,(x,y))

crashed=False
while not crashed:
    redrawWindow()
    bgX-=1.4
    bgX2-=1.4
    if bgX<bg.get_width()*-1:
        bgX=bg.get_width()
    elif bgX2<bg.get_width()*-1:
        bgX2=bg.get_width()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            crashed=True

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
                y_change=-1*speed
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
                y_change=0.7*speed
    y+=y_change
    test(x,y)
    player_rect.clamp_ip(mainDisplay_rect)
    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that your `y` values is within the correct range.
Since in pygame the top-left corner is `(0,0)` you want to have positive values (so it does not go over the top) and you want his lowest point to be less than the `height` values you defined. Usually a character position is defined from its top-left corner, so you check `y>0` and `y<height-height_character`.

In your example the check could be added after y is updated (`y+=y_change`). There are several ways to do this, but one easy and understandable could be:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

width=800
height=800
x=(width*0.45)
y=(height*0.6)
bgspeed=30
x_change=0
y_change=0
speed=2.5

mainDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption("jetpack")

bg=pygame.image.load("bg.jpg")
bg=pygame.transform.scale(bg,(width,height))
bgX=0
bgX2=bg.get_width()

dababy_jetpack=pygame.image.load("dababy.png")
dababy_jetpack.convert()
rect=dababy_jetpack.get_rect()
rect.center=0,0
player_rect=dababy_jetpack.get_rect(topleft=(200,200))
mainDisplay_rect=mainDisplay.get_rect()

jetpacker=pygame.image.load("dababy.png")
jetpacker=pygame.transform.scale(jetpacker,(100,200))

mainDisplay_rect=mainDisplay.get_rect()
player_rect=jetpacker.get_rect()



def redrawWindow():
    mainDisplay.blit(bg,(bgX,0))
    mainDisplay.blit(bg,(bgX2,0))
    pygame.display.update()

clock=pygame.time.Clock()

def test(x,y):
    mainDisplay.blit(jetpacker,(x,y))

crashed=False
while not crashed:
    redrawWindow()
    bgX-=1.4
    bgX2-=1.4
    if bgX<bg.get_width()*-1:
        bgX=bg.get_width()
    elif bgX2<bg.get_width()*-1:
        bgX2=bg.get_width()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            crashed=True

        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
                y_change=-1*speed
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
                y_change=0.7*speed
    y+=y_change
    # check border
    # at the bottom, you want your top left point of the character to stop
    # at height_screen-height_character (since 0,0 is the top left)
    if y>height-200:  # this 200 is the height of your character
        y=height-200
    # at the top, just avoid negative values
    elif y<0:
        y=0
    test(x,y)
    player_rect.clamp_ip(mainDisplay_rect)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

For me it works fine. Does it help?